# There can only be one UIMenuController instance

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller

I got

> There can only be one UIMenuController.

runtime error when I customized two different menu controller.I need this,how to fix it?Codes in Swift is better.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different storyboard id for a single viewcontroller or you can also pass some parameter to UIMenuController to load it dynamically